# Hide NFC app from "Choose Application" list / Disable start by external NFC intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, nfc, intentfilter

I'm currently writing a couple of NFC enabled apps for Android and wanted to know how I can stop my application from being in the "choose application" list that's opened whenever a tag is scanned from the launcher or a non-NFC app. I only want my apps to be able to read the tags when they are open.

[image]

My current intent filters:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
</intent-filter>
<meta-data android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED" android:resource="@xml/nfc_tech_filter" />
```

nfc_tech_filter.xml:

```
<tech-list>
    <tech>android.nfc.tech.MifareUltralight</tech>
</tech-list>
<tech-list>
    <tech>android.nfc.tech.Ndef</tech>
</tech-list>
```

Comment: Which intent-filters are registered to your app at the moment? You can find them in your manifest file.

Comment: Added my current filters.

Comment: Alright, I've undeleted and edited my answer. It should now fit your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You currently have a couple of NFC related intent filters in your app's manifest:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
</intent-filter>
```

By adding such intent filters to the manifest of your app, you indicate that certain activities should be *started* (or presented as options in the intent chooser if multiple activities are registered for the same intents) upon these NFC tag discovery events.

Consequently, you need to *remove* those intent filters from the *AndroidManifest.xml* if you don't want your app to be launchable by those intents.

However, you would then also lose the ability to listen for those intents while an activity of your app is in the foreground. Since NFC intents are activity intents, you can't receive them through dynamically registered broadcast receivers (cf. [RubbelDieKatz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6203984/rubbeldiekatz)'s answer). Instead, the Android API provides alternative means to catch NFC related events while an activity of your app is displayed in the foreground (this also allows your app to get precedence over other apps, which is not possible with manifest-based NFC intent filters):

1. Since API level 10 (basically since the beginning of Android NFC), Android features the foreground dispatch system. You can register your foreground activity to receive NFC events by using the method `NfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch()` upon `onResume()` (don't forget to unregister when your activity loses focus in `onPause()`):

   ```
   public void onResume() {
       super.onResume();
       PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);
       NfcAdapter adapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
       adapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, pendingIntent, null, null);
   }

   public void onPause() {
       super.onPause();
       NfcAdapter adapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
       adapter.disableForegroundDispatch(this);
   }
   ```

   You could even register to receive only a specific subset of NFC discovery events by providing the optional tech-list and intent-filters arguments to `enableForegroundDispatch()`.

   Once you registered your activity with the foreground dispatch system, you will receive NFC events through the `onNewIntent()` callback:

   ```
   public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
       Tag tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);

       ...
   }
   ```
2. Starting with API level 19, there is the new NFC reader mode API. You can now register to receive regular callbacks (instead of going through the intent dispatch which sometimes causes soome hickups). You can do this by using the method `NfcAdpater.enableReaderMode()`:

   ```
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

       ...

       NfcAdapter adapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
       adapter.enableReaderMode(this, this, NfcAdapter.FLAG_READER_NFC_A, null);
   }
   ```

   By using other flags in addition to (or instead of) `NfcAdapter.FLAG_READER_NFC_A` you could set to reader mode to listen for other tag technologies as well.

   You will then receive callbacks upon tag discovery (the receiver needs to implement the callback interface `NfcAdapter.ReaderCallback`):

   ```
   public void onTagDiscovered(Tag tag) {
       ...
   }
   ```

Also see [What's the difference between enableReaderMode and enableForegroundDispatch?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33633736/2425802) for a more detailed comparison between the two options.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, I am using the foreground dispatch system already, my apps are now working as expected. I also removed the filters in my manifest.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the [NFC and Tech Discovered `intent-filters`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc.html). You could remove them and register intent listeners programmatically in your app.

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
</intent-filter>
```

About registering the intent: [Here's a very good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4805733/6203984).

> In your `onCreate` method you can register a receiver like this:
>
> ```
> private BroadcastReceiver receiver;
>
> @Override
> public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
>
>   // your oncreate code should be
>
>   IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
>   filter.addAction("SOME_ACTION");
>   filter.addAction("SOME_OTHER_ACTION");
>
>   receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
>     @Override
>     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
>       //do something based on the intent's action
>     }
>   };
>      registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
> }
> ```
>
> Remember to run this in the `onDestroy` method:
>
> ```
>  @Override
>  protected void onDestroy() {
>   if (receiver != null) {
>    unregisterReceiver(receiver);
>    receiver = null;
>   }
>   super.onDestroy();
>  }
> ```

Another interesting quote from the answer below that one:

> One important point that people forget to mention is the life time of
>   the `Broadcast Receiver`. The difference of programmatically
>   registering it from  registering in **AndroidManifest.xml** is that.
>   In the manifest file, it doesn't depend on application life time.
>   While when programmatically registering it it does depend on the
>   application life time. This means that if you register in
>   **AndroidManifest.xml**, you can catch the broadcasted intents even when your application is not running.
>
> **Edit:** The mentioned note is no longer true as of Android 3.1, the Android system excludes all receiver from receiving intents by default
>   if the corresponding application has never been started by the user or
>   if the user explicitly stopped the application via the Android menu
>   (in Manage → Application).
>   https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-3.1.html
>
> This is an additional security feature as the user can be sure that
>   only the applications he started will receive broadcast intents.
>
> So it can be understood as receivers programmatically registered in
>   Application's `onCreate()` would have same effect with ones declared
>   in **AndroidManifest.xml** from Android 3.1 above.

If you unregister your receivers when your activity is killed, your application won't receive these broadcasts anymore.