# Enable/Disable android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED IntentFilter

Tags: android, nfc, intentfilter

I'd like to disable `android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED` IntentFilter depending on users' settings choice,
to avoid the choosing app dialog shows up.

In order to do this, I've created an activity-alias in my Android Manifest file and change its state through PackageManager:

`Anroid Manifest File`

```
<activity
    android:name=".activities.ActivitySplash"
    android:configChanges="orientation"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity-alias
    android:name=".AliasActivitySplash"
    android:targetActivity=".activities.ActivitySplash"
    android:exported="true"
    android:enabled="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"/>
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"
        android:resource="@xml/techlist"/>
</activity-alias>
```

`Activity Alias State Management:`

```
public void enableAlias() {
    int newState = PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED;
    _packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(new ComponentName(_packageName, _packageName + "." + 
    "AliasActivitySplash"), newState, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
}
public void disableAlias() {
    int newState = PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED;
    _packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(new ComponentName(_packageName, _packageName + "." + 
    "AliasActivitySplash"), newState, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
}
```

I get a `java.lang.SecurityException` everytime i try to change the alias state. I've read installing the app as a system app should solve the issue.

Exception caught:

```
    java.lang.SecurityException: Attempt to change component state; pid=10766, uid=10329, component=packagename/packagename.AliasActivitySplash
        at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2071)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2039)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1987)
        at android.content.pm.IPackageManager$Stub$Proxy.setComponentEnabledSetting(IPackageManager.java:7336)
        at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(ApplicationPackageManager.java:2554)
        at packagename.activities.alias.ActivitySplashAliasManager.disableAlias(ActivitySplashAliasManager.java:27)
        at packagename.fragments.FragmentPreferences.onPreferenceChange(FragmentPreferences.java:83)
        at androidx.preference.Preference.callChangeListener(Preference.java:1118)
        at androidx.preference.TwoStatePreference.onClick(TwoStatePreference.java:67)
        at androidx.preference.Preference.performClick(Preference.java:1182)
        at androidx.preference.Preference.performClick(Preference.java:1166)
        at androidx.preference.SwitchPreferenceCompat.performClick(SwitchPreferenceCompat.java:193)
        at androidx.preference.Preference$1.onClick(Preference.java:181)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7140)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7117)
        at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:801)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27351)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
2019-10-24 09:21:43.863 10766-10766/packagename E/Test:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
     Caused by: android.os.RemoteException: Remote stack trace:
        at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.setEnabledSetting(PackageManagerService.java:21250)
        at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.setComponentEnabledSetting(PackageManagerService.java:21184)
        at android.content.pm.IPackageManager$Stub.onTransact(IPackageManager.java:3473)
        at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.onTransact(PackageManagerService.java:4015)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1021)
```

Am I doing something wrong or is there any other way to do this?

Comment: show the exception stacktrace

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hide NFC app from "Choose Application" list / Disable start by external NFC intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45934270/hide-nfc-app-from-choose-application-list-disable-start-by-external-nfc-inte)

Answer (score 0):

I've finally solved it. The problem was the way I was getting the packagename. My app has multiple flavor configuration and i was trying to disable/enable a component from the other flavor installed on my device