# Should NfcAdapter.enableReaderMode in foreground Activity override the intent tag dispatch system?

Tags: android, nfc, android-10.0

In Android 10 I noticed I get a Toast message from the OS stating "No supported application for this NFC tag" or "No supported app for this NFC tag" (depending on the device):

[image]

The weird thing is that I see the Toast while `enableReaderMode` is active in the foreground Activity. In all previous versions of Android, `enableReaderMode` would override the Android intent tag dispatch system. Is this a bug in Android 10?

I know `enableForegroundDispatch` also exists, and that API *does* seem to override the intent tag dispatch system even in Android 10. But I'd like to keep control over the NFC discovery sound which is only provided by `enableReaderMode`.

I also know that I can declare an intent-filter in my manifest to get rid of the Toast while continuing to use `enableReaderMode`, but that also has unintended side effects (e.g. my app could be launched while reading the NFC tag from the device home screen which I don't want).

Comment: For me this happens randomly on Android 10 (i.e. sometimes reader mode gets activated, sometimes not). [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61142449/5128464) looks related (and contains some insights)...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it seems to be a bug as Android OS fires a new tagDiscovery event under the following conditions:

- Use enableReaderMode instead of enableForegroundDispatch
- Read or write a card
- While the card is still in proximity call disableReaderMode.

Since this triggers an OS level event, it can pause focused activity, might show a toast screen or show related application select box.

To workaround the problem,

**Workaround 1:**

- Try connecting the card in a loop until an IOException is fired. (which means card is not in proximity anymore)
- Then call disableReaderMode

Cons: You may need to show a message to the user to remove the tag/card from the device proximity.

**Workaround 2:**

- Use legacy enableForegroundDispatch / disableForegroundDispatch along with readerMode

Cons: Popup do not gets displayed, however tag discovery sound still gets triggered.

Both solutions do not need intent-filter to be defined.

Sample code that implements both workarounds is below.

```
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.nfc.NfcAdapter;
import android.nfc.Tag;
import android.nfc.tech.IsoDep;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    private NfcAdapter nfcAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //Assuming nfc adapter is present and active, such checks are ignored for code clarity,
        //production code must check for hardware nfc adapter existence
        nfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this); //Get the default NFC adapter from OS

        //Additional initialization code
    }

    private void onTagDiscovered(Tag tag)
    {
        try
        {
            if (tag == null)
                return;

            //Assumption: We're using an NFC card that supports IsoDep
            IsoDep iso = IsoDep.get(tag);

            if (iso == null)
                return;

            iso.setTimeout(1000);
            iso.connect();

            //doCardReadWrite(iso);

            iso.close();

            //Workaround 1
            //Wait until the card has been removed from the range of NFC
            //Then finish the activity
            while(true)
            {
                try
                {
                    iso.connect();
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                    iso.close();
                }
                catch (IOException | InterruptedException e)
                {
                    //On this example, once we're done with the activity, we want to close it
                    //then onPause event will call disableReaderMode, at that moment we don't want a card to be in proximity
                    onCardRemoved();
                    break;
                }
            }
            //End of Workaround 1
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Tag disconnected. Reason: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    private void onCardRemoved()
    {
        this.finish();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();

        //Workaround 2
        //Legacy nfc reader activation method, just enabled it but we won't use it
        //(to fully support [e.g. OS version < v4.4.4] you must override onNewIntent(Intent intent) method as well)

        //create intent/tag filters to be used with enableForegroundDispatch
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                this,
                0,
                new Intent(this, this.getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP),
                0
        );

        IntentFilter tagDetected = new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED);
        tagDetected.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
        IntentFilter[] writeTagFilters = new IntentFilter[]{tagDetected};

        nfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, pendingIntent, writeTagFilters, null);
        //End of Workaround 2

        //ReaderMode activation
        Bundle options = new Bundle();
        options.putInt(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_READER_PRESENCE_CHECK_DELAY, 1000);//Presence check interval
        final int READER_FLAGS = NfcAdapter.FLAG_READER_NFC_A | NfcAdapter.FLAG_READER_SKIP_NDEF_CHECK | NfcAdapter.FLAG_READER_NO_PLATFORM_SOUNDS;
        nfcAdapter.enableReaderMode(this, new NfcAdapter.ReaderCallback()
        {
            @Override
            public void onTagDiscovered(Tag tag)
            {
                MainActivity.this.onTagDiscovered(tag);
            }
        }, READER_FLAGS, options);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause()
    {
        nfcAdapter.disableReaderMode(this);

        //Workaround 2
        nfcAdapter.disableForegroundDispatch(this);

        super.onPause();
    }
}
```